# How to reuse a ViewController in NavigationController chain programmatically

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I realize this problem after I integrate google drive api into my app today. As below gif image showed, there is bunch of nested folders in tableView.

It is under UINavigationController, so normally I will do a pushView `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` to open a new ViewController, but I don't know how many levels it would be, then it is kind of end game.

Per my experience, the gif image is just refreshing the data source in the same ViewController, although it looks like a pushView action. Maybe it add some animation to make it like opening a new ViewController and it records the previous data source(the folders) when push that back navigation button.

My question is what is the property way to deal with it in real world apps? I means many apps will face the same circumstances.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a google drive project in Github I get a solution.

They just reopen the viewController itself recursively to solve this problem. Although it will create many co-exist viewController instances, it is memory consuming, but I didn't found another way to do it.

After a few time of test, I opened like 20 depth of viewControllers, my app didn't crash, from debug memory graph, I could see opening a VC taking just a little bit of memory, nice!

Below is my code, hope it could help somebody who face this particular problem.

##### my recursive GoogleDriveVC

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 52
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        
        if title == nil { title = "Google Drive" }
        
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        listAudioFilesAndFolders()
    }
    
    func listAudioFilesAndFolders() {
        showSpinner()
        // for root folder
        var id = "root"
        if let folderID = self.folderID {
            id = folderID
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            self?.googleAPIs?.listFiles(id, onCompleted: { files, error in
                guard error == nil, files != nil else {
                    print("Err: \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                
                // filter the files before passing it.
                self?.audioFilesAndFolders = files?.filter { $0.mimeType == "audio/mpeg" || $0.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}
                print("load data in google drive's current level complete")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                    self?.removeSpinner()
                }
            })
        }
    }

extension GoogleDriveFilesViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        guard let files = self.audioFilesAndFolders else { return }
        let file = files[indexPath.row]
        // open a new VC when file type is 'folder'
        if file.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" {
            let vc = GoogleDriveFilesViewController()
            vc.folderID = file.identifier
            vc.title = file.name
            vc.modelController = self.modelController
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

##### google api

```
    public func listFiles(_ folderID: String, onCompleted: @escaping ([GTLRDrive_File]?, Error?) -> ()) {
        let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
        query.pageSize = 100
        query.q = "'\(folderID)' in parents"
//        self.service.shouldFetchNextPages = true
        self.service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, results, error) in
            onCompleted((results as? GTLRDrive_FileList)?.files, error)
        }
    }
```